# Problems using store_json() from shinylogs on shiny-server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to deploy a shiny app which uses the shinylogs  `store_json()`-function to a shiny-server running on Ubuntu 20.04. However, no matter which path i use, it doesn't save the files and no error occurs in my logs.

Everything works perfectly fine with `write.table()` so i was wondering if shinylogs needs any special configuration running on shiny-server.

I adabted the minimal working example from https://github.com/dreamRs/shinylogs/blob/master/examples/store_json.R. The app is executed properly and i can play around with it, but it won't save any logs.

Since the app i want to deploy is not written by me, i kind of depend on using shinylogs so i am very grateful for any help!

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinylogs)

  tmp <- "~"

  # Classir Iris clustering with Shiny
  ui <- fluidPage(

    headerPanel("Iris k-means clustering"),

    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
          inputId = "xcol",
          label = "X Variable",
          choices = names(iris)
        ),
        selectInput(
          inputId = "ycol",
          label = "Y Variable",
          choices = names(iris),
          selected = names(iris)[[2]]
        ),
        numericInput(
          inputId = "clusters",
          label = "Cluster count",
          value = 3,
          min = 1,
          max = 9
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot1")
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # Store JSON with logs in the temp dir
    track_usage(
      storage_mode = store_json(path = tmp)
    )

    # classic server logic

    selectedData <- reactive({
      iris[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
    })

    clusters <- reactive({
      kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      palette(c("#E41A1C", "#377EB8", "#4DAF4A", "#984EA3",
                "#FF7F00", "#FFFF33", "#A65628", "#F781BF", "#999999"))

      par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
      plot(selectedData(),
           col = clusters()$cluster,
           pch = 20, cex = 3)
      points(clusters()$centers, pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this one by simply inlcuding `library(jsonlite)` since its `write_json()` function is called by shinylogs using `::` . I don't really have an explanation though. So if anyone knows why this makes problems let me know!

Comment: Had the exact same issue and loading the `jsonlite` library did indeed solve it, so thanks for posting your solution here.